# How can I query this JSON payload in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json

**JSON**

```
payload in column: message
 [
   { "id":1, "intvalue":14, "time":"2018-05-13 12:51:34" }, 
   { "id":2, "intvalue":13, "time":"2018-05-13 12:51:33" }, 
   { "id":3, "intvalue":3, "time":"2018-05-13 12:51:32" }
 ]
```

**Query**

```
select `message` -> '$.intvalue' intvalue FROM mqtt.tbl_messages
```

[MySQL ver: 5.7.X](https://www.mysql.com/)

I want to display all `intvalues`. But I get empty result. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your payload is an JSON Array, so that the correct query should be

```
select `message` -> '$[*].intvalue' intvalue FROM mqtt.tbl_messages
```

Comment: Thanks. works perfectly. I tried empty [] without * or any value.